# Add enemy on stage within a limit

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am making an application just for testing some codes. There is a ship that is shooting enemies. These enemies comes down from the top of the screen and they are added with this code (The reason why its 4 different enemies is that they all have different behaviors)

```
-(void) addEnemy {   

int randomX = arc4random() % screenWidth; 

Enemy* anEnemy;

int diceRoll = arc4random() % 4; 

if (diceRoll == 0) {
    anEnemy = [Enemy createEnemy:@"enemy1" framesToAnimate:24];

} else if (diceRoll == 1) {
    anEnemy = [Enemy createEnemy:@"enemy2" framesToAnimate:17];

} else if (diceRoll == 2) {
    anEnemy = [Enemy createEnemy:@"enemy3" framesToAnimate:14];

} else if (diceRoll == 3) {

    anEnemy = [Enemy createEnemy:@"enemy4" framesToAnimate:24];
}

[self addChild:anEnemy z:depthLevelBelowBullet];
anEnemy.position = ccp ( randomX , screenHeight + 200);

numberOfEnemiesOnstage ++; 
}
```

The enemies are being added with a random x-value which means enemies sometimes is half outside the screen. Like this:

[image]

How do limit the x-value from both sides of the screen so this won't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not considering the image width when you're calculating the random x position. You have to move the randomX declaration and initialization after you've created the enemy objects so the `textureRect` property will be properly set.

```
int offset = (int)[Enemy textureRect].size.width / 2;
int randomX = (arc4random() % (screenWidth - (2 * offset))) + offset;
```

Comment: I get the warning +Classmethod textureRect not found

Comment: Well, I supposed that `Enemy` was a subclass of `CCSprite`. You have to put half of the image's width in the `offset` variable.

Comment: I made it work now by putting in the direct value of the width of the enemy. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct but if you are using CCSprite it will be a little different. Try the following code:

```
-(void) addEnemy {   

int randomX = arc4random() % screenWidth; 

Enemy* anEnemy;

int diceRoll = arc4random() % 4; 
int halfWidth;

if (diceRoll == 0) {
    anEnemy = [Enemy createEnemy:@"enemy1" framesToAnimate:24];
    halfWidth = anEnemy.contentSize.width/2;

} else if (diceRoll == 1) {
    anEnemy = [Enemy createEnemy:@"enemy2" framesToAnimate:17];
    halfWidth = anEnemy.contentSize.width/2;

} else if (diceRoll == 2) {
    anEnemy = [Enemy createEnemy:@"enemy3" framesToAnimate:14];
    halfWidth = anEnemy.contentSize.width/2;

} else if (diceRoll == 3) {

    anEnemy = [Enemy createEnemy:@"enemy4" framesToAnimate:24];
    halfWidth = anEnemy.contentSize.width/2;
}

if(randomX < halfWidth) {
    randomX = halfWidth;
} else {
    randomX = randomX-halfWidth;
}

[self addChild:anEnemy z:depthLevelBelowBullet];
anEnemy.position = ccp ( randomX , screenHeight + 200);

numberOfEnemiesOnstage ++; 
}
```

Comment: Hmm for some reason every enemy was now spawning as far to the right side of the screen so we just could see the half of them

Comment: Sorry I made a small error in the code I posted but I have updated it to reflect the new code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but i couldn't make that code work either. Some enemies are still spawning outside the screen:/ When I shoot enemies they aren't being shot if not the bullet hits the exact center of the enemy. It seems like they doesn't have any content, just visible. Maybe this is making the contentSize/2 not work? The code for the enemy sprite is `enemySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_enemy0001.png", theBaseImage]]; 
        [self addChild:enemySprite];
        enemySprite.position = ccp (0, 0); `